# Use DAX Measure in "Values" or "Legend" Field in Power BI Scatter Plot

Tags: powerbi, dax, scatter-plot, tableau-desktop

I have a DAX Measure that I need to use in either the "Values" or the "Legend" Field. I am unable to accomplish this as a calculated column because the Measure relies on a Parameter Value attached to a slicer which cannot be used in a calculated column, but Power BI is not allowing me to use the Measure in either of these fields even though the return a text value.

I know this is generally the issue because a Measure returns a summarized value, but I would imagine this is possible as it's very easy to do this in Tableau, but I can't see to find a way to get this to work in Power BI.

Here is the measure:

```
Meets Criteria = SWITCH(
    TRUE(),
    Sheet1[Revenue] > 'Rev Param'[Rev Param Value], 
    "IN-IN",
    Sheet1[Revenue] > 45000 && Sheet1[Revenue] < 60000,
     "IN-OUT",
      "OUT"
      )
```

The Rev Param (parameter) is attached to a slider slicer that allows the viewer to change the revenue detail that will adjust the visual. I am needing to use this to create three classifiers for a Company being either "IN-IN", "IN-OUT", or "OUT-OUT" based on revenue value.  below is a copy of how the visual should look in Power BI based on how i created it in Tableau. These three categories will then allow me to change the shape and color of the data points on the scatter plot, or at least that's how I want it to work.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

[image]